# How to export models to a CSV file using Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, csv

I'd like to export all database entries into a csv using Rails 3.2. I've been following [these](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel) instructions:

My controller:
**EDIT: I've changed from class method to instance method**

```
...
elsif params[:reference] == 'exportnews'
  @data = News.find(:all, :order => "date_posted desc", :conditions => "#{Settings.show} = 1", :limit => "5")
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to root_url }
    format.csv { send_data @data.to_csv }
  end
else
...
```

My model:

```
  class News < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :content, :date_posted, :heading, :hidden, :reference, :title, :user
      def to_csv(options = {})
          CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
            csv << column_names
            all.each do |product|
              csv << product.attributes.values_at(*column_names).map(&:to_csv)
            end
          end
        end
    end
```

yet when I visit the specified url (I've created a route in `config/routes.rb` I get a csv file with the following details:

`#<News:0x007fef657d69f8>   #<News:0x007fef632b95a8>    #<News:0x007fef632b8ec8>    #<News:0x007fef632b8680>    #<News:0x007fef632b7e38>`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not calling your method this way (you're calling the original `.to_csv` method instead. Try doing this in your view:

```
format.csv { send_data @data.map(&:to_csv }
```

Comment: I've assumed you closed the `)`. I've tried that and didn't work either. I got this error `undefined local variable or method `all' for #<News:0x007fb0a7cdcdf0>`